A more efficient algorithm in finding the number of distinct decompositions a number has using only repdigits
This is a problem from a previous semester that I am trying to upsolve. I am trying to solve a problem involving the total number of ways of decomposing a number using only repdigits. A repdigit is a positive integer consisting of only a single digit, e.g. numbers 1-9, 11, 22, 3333, and so on.
To illustrate, say we have n = 3:
1+1+1
1+2
2+1
3
which totals 4. Note that 1+2 and 2+1 are considered distinct here.
Now I have a solution in python that uses dynamic programming. I thought that it would be efficient enough but apparently it still exceeds the time limit (we use an online judge created by the university to automatically check code). The limits of the problem is up to n == 90000 with only a 5 second limit. We can only use python. For reference, here is my code:
def count_repdigit_decompositions(n: int) -> int:
    rep: list[int] = []
    for digit in range(1, 10):
        repdigit = digit
        while repdigit <= n:
            rep.append(repdigit)
            repdigit = repdigit * 10 + digit
    
    rep.sort()

    dp = [0] * (n + 1)
    dp[0] = 1 

    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        for repdigit in rep:
            dp[i] += dp[i - repdigit]
    return dp[n]

I have tried looking into oeis (https://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C+1%2C+2%2C+4%2C+8%2C+16%2C+32%2C+64%2C+128%2C+256%2C+511%2C+1022&go=Search) for the pattern to this but it only shows for the palindromic decomposition which makes sense since the first few palindromes match exactly of that of the repdigits. How do I make this more efficient?

@folengateis I was redirected by code review se to ask it here, I'm confused, where do I actually ask this?

that wasn't a composition either, because i relied only on your example. how do you handle 15?

@folengateis 15 produces 16300 different answers. Examples are 11+1+1+1+1, 11+2+2, 9+2+2+2, 8+1+2+2, 1+11+1+1+1 and so on.

@Lesserrafim this problem is going to give an answer on the order of 10**27063 for n=90000.  Are you sure 1,2 is different from 2,1?

@James yes I'm sure. What I am not sure is if 90000 was really used for the test case.

What does "upsolve" mean? (In your first question I thought it's a typo, but now that you wrote it again...)

And you actually need the whole huge number with 27064 digits?

@nocomment upsolve generally means solving a problem after the actual event ends. I am not sure with the 27064 digits part but I am thinking I might need it since no modulo reduction was given.

@no comment - The OP is asking for help making their solution more efficient.

@JeremiahHerberg I know. Why are you saying that?

@no comment - that is what "upsolving" means in the context of this question

how long does your program take for n==90000?

@JeremiahHerberg They had already replied saying what it actually means.

@MattTimmermans 7.44 secs for n == 90000, 6.88 secs for n == 80000

You're not taking advantage of the relationships between the repdigit numbers.
Imagine repdigit were just the numbers 1 to 9. Then your
        for repdigit in rep:
            dp[i] += dp[i - repdigit]

would be equivalent to this:
        dp[i] += sum(dp[i-9:i])

And for the next entry it would be this:
        dp[i+1] += sum(dp[i-8:i+1])

These two sums are related, they mostly overlap, so you can compute the next sum from the previous with a smaller adjusting calculation. Just two or three operations instead of nine.
Similarly for larger repdigits like 11, 22, ..., 99. There, dp[i] += sum(dp[i-99:i:11]) and dp[i+11] += sum(dp[i-88:i+11:11]) are related.
I tried your code with n=90000, it took around 8.5 seconds. So I think this optimization will get it under the 5 seconds limit.

Wouldn't still this be the same thing in terms of time complexity? I also tried a sliding window approach for repdigits 1-9 (still exceeds the time limit) but cannot seem to implement a similar sliding window to other repdigits.

@Lesserrafim Yes, same complexity class, but faster by a constant factor large enough to get under the time limit, since you're already close. Same idea as Matt's answer, who dropped from 6 seconds to 2.1 seconds.

For n=90000, your code runs in 6 seconds on my macbook -- not far off the mark.
Most of the time is taken up by adding very large integers, so we can do better by reducing the number of these additions.
Here is an implementation that uses a concept from digital signal processing called a cascaded integrator-comb filter, taking advantage of the fact that the relevant repdigits can be divided into 5 groups of 9 evenly-spaced numbers.  Using the CIC technique, we can do only 3 operations per group per N, which should result in about a third the total number of additions.
For n=90000, this version takes 2.1 seconds on my macbook:
def repdigit_decomposition_fast(n: int) -> int:
    rep1 = 1
    cics = []
    while rep1 <= n:
        cics.append([0] * (n+1))
        rep1 = rep1*10 + 1
    out = [0]*(n+1)
    out[0] = 1
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        total=0
        rep1 = 1
        for group in range(0, len(cics)):
            rep10 = rep1*10
            if i >= rep1:
                sum = cics[group][i-rep1] + out[i-rep1]
                cics[group][i-rep1]=0 # free up this memory
                if i>=rep10:
                    sum-=out[i-rep10]
                cics[group][i] = sum
                total += sum
            rep1 = rep1*10+1
        out[i] = total
    return out[n];


Just for fun, I'll also mention that another DSP technique -- partial fraction expansion of the transfer function -- can be used to sovle this problem without iterating over all n... but that's a lot more code than I want to write.  https://www.dsprelated.com/freebooks/filters/Partial_Fraction_Expansion.html

This approach is very fast, but I forgot to mention that we also had a memory limit of 1GB. Submitting this code gave a memory limit. Sorry for not mentioning about it.

That should be fixed now

Apparently, it is still too slow. I don't know why
